# Concept behind SIFT descriptor

Tags: opencv, sift

I have read some literature about SIFT and watched some videos also. I understood most of the concepts behind SIFT but one thing which confuses me is about SIFT descriptors.

In SIFT:

- we find a keypoint
- we take `16 x 16` pixels around the keypoint.
- Divide the `16 x 16` blocks into 16 number of `4 x 4` blocks
- Calculate a `8 bin` histogram for each `4 x 4` block
- Therefore, we get **`4 x 4 x 8 = 128`** dimension SIFT descriptor for this keypoint.

[image]

**My confusion:**

- Lets say, my image have 50 keypoints.
- The SIFT descriptor i receive for this image (**i.e. Mat descriptor**) has `128 columns` and `1 row`.....why???
- I got `128 columns` and `1 row` for a single keypoint then if i am getting 50 keypoints then shouldn't it be a `50 rows` and `128 colmuns` matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opencv's 2.4.8 source says you should get n by 128 descriptor matrix, where n is the number of keypoints. You can see *calcDescriptors()* creates descriptor for every keypoint by refrencing *descriptors* rows.

```
static void calcDescriptors(const vector<Mat>& gpyr, const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                            Mat& descriptors, int nOctaveLayers, int firstOctave )
{
    int d = SIFT_DESCR_WIDTH, n = SIFT_DESCR_HIST_BINS;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++ )
    {
        // [...]
        // some unrelevant code 

        calcSIFTDescriptor(img, ptf, angle, size*0.5f, d, n, descriptors.ptr<float>((int)i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i checked it too in my code and found that i got confused uselessly....thanks !!!